# Particle Filter -Matlab

Tags: matlab, particle-filter

I've implemented the particle filter as follow:

System Model:

```
X=x+t*cos(theta)*V; 
y=y+t*sin(theta)*V; 
theta= theta+omega*t;
```

in which V, omega are velocity and angle velocity respectively. In addition, the observations consist of a noisy version of the distance from the left upper corner of the box.

However, I am not sure my code is correct.( distance of particle from each other is increasing), can any body please help me about that?

**second**: I want to show the object which I want track in the matlab, but I've tried different approaches, still unsuccessful. would you plz help me about this part as well.

```
%#######################################################
clc;
clear all;
close all;

N=400; % numebr of Particles
T=100; % Time Steps
x0=zeros(1,N);
theta0=zeros(1,N);
y0=zeros(1,N);
v=5;
omega=pi/4;
%%
% x theta, y and Omega and V 
particle=zeros(3,N);
w = ones(T,N);                   % Importance weights.
resamplingScheme=1;

for t=2:T

 %% Prediction Steps
   for p=1:N
     v_noisy=v+rand*.5;
     omega_nosiy=omega*.2;
     particle(1,p)=x0(p)+t*v_noisy*cosd(theta0(p));
     particle(2,p)=y0(p)+t*v_noisy*sind(theta0(p));
     particle(3,p)=theta0(p)+omega_nosiy*t;
 end

%%  IMPORTANCE WEIGHTS:
 for p=1:N
       distance=sqrt( particle(1,p)^2+ particle(2,p)^2); 
       if distance< 4 || distance > 25
            distance = .7;
      else
             distance=.3;
      end
      w(t,p) =distance;    
  end
  w(t,:) = w(t,:)./sum(w(t,:));                 % Normalise the weights.

%% SELECTION STEP:

if resamplingScheme == 1
    outIndex = residualR(1:N,w(t,:)');        % Residual resampling.
elseif resamplingScheme == 2
    outIndex = systematicR(1:N,w(t,:)');      % Systematic resampling.
else  
    outIndex = multinomialR(1:N,w(t,:)');     % Multinomial resampling.  
end;
x0=particle(1,outIndex);
y0=particle(2,outIndex);
theta0=particle(3,outIndex);

clf;
hold on;
plot(x0,y0,'gx');
refresh;
drawnow;

end
```

Comment: Are you sure about the residualR() function?

Comment: you mean, may be it is not correct? I've checked with multinomialR and systematicR, the results are the same(mostly). Just one question, in your view other parts is OK?

Comment: OK, I am all in this problem.  I really enjoy this kind of stuff, but I'll need some help to understand the algorithm because I'm way more familiar with Kalman Filters if you're game @superMind.  It seems that the resampling index never changes, because the normalizing weights don't change.

Comment: I think I found the problem, most problem is because of wrong observation model

Comment: you should post your answer, I'll be sure to vote it up!

Comment: Ok here is my solution:  1. For the prediction model, it is necessary to define Vx and Vy instaed of just V fro every particles. and then whenever the agen hit the wall just reverse the the velocity 2. for observation model: it should be sth like this : d=sqrt((obs_x-x0)^2+(obs_y-y0)^2)) and ds=sqrt((xi-x0)^2+(yi-y0)^2). The xi and yi are particles coordination and obs_x/y are observations. The x0 and y0 are the point that we want to find the distance of agent and particle from. then send to N(d-ds,sigam) to calculate the weight. The N is Gaussian distribution.

Comment: If you solved your problem, please add the solution as a separate answer and accept it. That way, other users will now that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what, you should vectorize this code. You'll take a huge performance hit using these nested **for** loops. In general, in an interpreted language like Matlab, you should never use a **for** command unless you absolutely have to. Try something like this:

```
distance = sqrt(particle(1,:).^2 + particle(2,:).^2);
outOfBounds = distance < 4 | distance > 25; % note use of vectorized | operator instead of scalar || operator
w(t,outOfBounds) = 0.7;
w(t,~outOfBounds) = 0.3;
```